# Proving $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\arccos(\cos^2h)} {h}$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I want to show $\arcsin (\sin^2x) $ is not differentiable at $\pi/2+\pi k$. (if its true).

So far I have:
$$ \frac{\arcsin (\sin^2(\pi/2+\pi k +h))-\arcsin (\sin^2(\pi/2+\pi k))}{h}=\frac{\arcsin (\cos^2h)-\ \pi/2}{h} = \frac {\arccos (\cos^2 h)}{h} $$

so it's sufficient to wish to show this limit exists or doesn't exist:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\arccos(\cos^2h)} {h}$$

Not sure how to proceed.

EDIT: I edited the question to cover $-\pi/2 +2\pi k$ aswell. I feel the question didn't get enough attention.

I have been told by a friend it's solveable using l'hopitals rule looking at the one sided limits, however l'hopitals is 2 months ahead in my course. a little strange this problem appears now.

Comment: $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \arccos(\cos^2 h)$ is $0$. Your logic above didn't follow.

Comment: care to propose a way to approach your statement?

Comment: Graphing might be looked down upon but it seems the limit doesn't exist: [graph from wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+h+goes+to+0+of+arcos%28cos^2+h%29%2Fh&h=1)

Comment: Right. The limit of $\arccos(\cos^2h)/h$, not of $\arccos(\cos^2h)$. You dropped the $h$ in the denominator in your last line and that's why I said it didn't follow.

Comment: Ah. sorry. editing now.

Comment: So you basically reduced the problem to whether or not $\arccos(\cos^2x)$ is differentiable at $0$ (assuming your algebra is right). What facts about these functions are you allowed to use? Have you tried the chain rule?

Comment: I know arccos is differentiable at (-1,1). cos^2 differentiable at R. arccos is not necessarily differentiable at cos^2(0)=1, so I'm not sure how the chainrule applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function has period $\pi$, computing the limit at $\pi/2$ is sufficient. Now, where's the error?

The computation
$$
\arcsin\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+h\right)\right)-\arcsin\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2}=
\arcsin\cos^2 h-\frac{\pi}{2}=-\arccos\cos^2h
$$
is correct. Now your limit is exactly computing the derivative of $f(x)=\arccos\cos^2x$ at $0$.

The function is continuous and its derivative, except possibly at zero, exists:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}}=
\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{|\sin x|}
$$
and the limit of this at $0$ is different when computed from the left and from the right:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}f'(x)=1,\quad
\lim_{x\to 0-}f'(x)=-1.
$$

Now, I know that this uses l'Hôpital's theorem, but this is a guide. If $f$ were differentiable at $0$, the derivative should be $0$, because the function is even and non negative. So we want to show that
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x}\ge1
$$
holds for $0<x<k$ (for some $k>0$). This means
$$
\arccos\cos^2x>x
$$
or, since the cosine is decreasing in $[0,\pi/2]$,
$$
\cos^2x<\cos x
$$
which is true for $0<x<\pi/2$.

Comment: you found the limit of it's alleged derivative doesn't exist, which lemma is used to infer the limit doesn't exist in the original function?

Comment: because even the derivative of $|x|$ is not continuous at $0$ and $|x|$ is still continuous...

Comment: @Yaniv.Fish Yes, of course. Your problem is completely equivalent to $f(x)=\arccos\cos^2x$ being differentiable at $0$. I've added a proof independent from considering the limit of the derivatives.